# insert multiple arrays to database

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a multiple choice quiz and I don't know how to insert multiple arrays to database. I can insert the first 2 arrays using array_combine but cannot on the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th array. I can insert questions and answers but not the options A, B, C, and D.

I'm trying to do something like

foreach(array_combine($_POST['inQuestion'], $_POST['inAnswer'], $_POST['inA'], $_POST['inB'], $_POST['inC'], $_POST['inD']) as $question => $answer => $A => $B => $C => $D) {

Please help. Here is my code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btnCreate'])) {

        $inQuestion = array($_POST['inQuestion']);
        $inAnswer = array($_POST['inAnswer']);
        $inA = array($_POST['inA']);
        $inB = array($_POST['inB']);
        $inC = array($_POST['inC']);
        $inD = array($_POST['inD']);
        $inLesson = $_POST['inLesson'];
        $inQuizNo = $_POST['inQuizNo'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE title='$inLesson'";
        $query = mysql_query ($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $lessonID = $row['lessonID'];

        foreach(array_combine($_POST['inQuestion'], $_POST['inAnswer']) as $question => $answer) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (question, answer, A, B, C, D, lessonID, quizNo) VALUES ('$question', '$answer', '$A', '$B', '$C', '$D', '$lessonID', $inQuizNo)";
            $query = mysql_query( $sql ); 
        }

    }
?>

<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>Create Assessment - Multiple Choice</h4>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">

    <form method="post">

        <br>

        <div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <strong>Lesson</strong><br>
                <select class="form-control" name="inLesson">
                    <option></option>
                    <option disabled></option>

                    <?php
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE courseID='$_GET[courseID]'";
                        $query2 = mysql_query ($sql2);                          
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
                    ?>

                        <option><?php echo $row2['title']; ?></option>

                    <?php   } ?>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <strong>Quiz No.</strong><br>                   
                <input required type="number" class="form-control" name="inQuizNo" min="1" max="100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="pull-right">
                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" class="btn btn-info">
                <input type="button" value="Remove" id="removeButton" class="btn btn-warning">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br><br><br><br><br>

        <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
            <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="form-group">

                <h2><span class="label label-primary">No. 1</span></h2>
                <br><br>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>Question</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inQuestion[]' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Answer</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inAnswer[]' class="form-control">
                    <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>A</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inA[]' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>B</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inB[]' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>C</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inC[]' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>D</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inD[]' class="form-control">
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" name="btnCreate"  class="btn btn-success pull-right">Create Quiz
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: give your full code including html code. so that we understand what you want

Comment: what are the values types of these arrays ? and why do you have an array with one item in it?

Comment: would you mind giving us more information about what are you trying to reach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you are trying to insert multible rows INTO your database.

First, when you use the `[]` in HTML forms you don't have to declare it as an array in `php`

Second, each question will have a question name, answer, A,B,C,D

When you trying to create the HTML form you could use this format to keep track the question_id or number.

```
<label>Question</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inQuestion[1]' class="form-control">
```

Then you will be able to retrieve this item as `$_POST['inQuestion'][1]`

For Example, if you need 10 questions in your test page you can do it like this:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) : ?>
<form method="post"> 

   <div class="col-md-10">
        <label>Question</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inQuestion[<?=$i;?>]' class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Answer</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inAnswer[<?=$i;?>]' class="form-control">
        <br>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>A</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inA[<?=$i;?>]' class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>B</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inB[<?=$i;?>]' class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>C</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inC[<?=$i;?>]' class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>D</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inD[<?=$i;?>]' class="form-control">
        <br><br>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="go">

</form>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Also, why do you put the content of the Answers A,B,C,D to an array while you have them is columns in your database. Also use these variables in your query too.

```
$inA = $_POST['inA'];
$inB = $_POST['inB'];
$inC = $_POST['inC'];
$inD = $_POST['inD'];
```

Finally Let's try to insert your values now.

```
if($_POST['btnCreate']){

    // The form has been posted!

    $inLesson = $_POST['inLesson'];
    $inQuizNo = $_POST['inQuizNo'];

    $questionsCount = count($_POST['inQuestion']);

    $items = array();

    // Since we should have the same size of arrays.
    // Also the empty validation has been handled before this step!
    for($i = 0; $i < $questionsCount; $i++){
            $temp = array();
        $temp['inQuestion']   = $_POST['inQuestion'][$i];
        $temp['inAnswer']     = $_POST['inAnswer'][$i];
        $temp['inA']          = $_POST['inA'][$i];
        $temp['inB']          = $_POST['inB'][$i];
        $temp['inC']          = $_POST['inC'][$i];
        $temp['inD']          = $_POST['inD'][$i];
            $items[] = $temp;
    }


    // Now items should have an array of all questions.

    foreach($items as $item){

        $SQL = 'INSERT INTO `test` (question, answer, A, B, C, D, lessonID, quizNo) VALUES (
                                                                                            "'.$item['inQuestion'].'",
                                                                                            "'.$item['inAnswer'].'",
                                                                                            "'.$item['inA'].'",
                                                                                            "'.$item['inB'].'",
                                                                                            "'.$item['inC'].'",
                                                                                            "'.$item['inD'].'",
                                                                                            "'.$inLesson.'",
                                                                                            "'.$inQuizNo.'")';

       $query = mysql_query( $SQL );
    } // End Foreach
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error. Undefined variable 1 on this line >> for($i = 0; $i < $$questionsCount; $i++){

Comment: I fixed the for loop, you can try it now.

Comment: I finally got my answer sir. You're such a very big help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['btnCreate'])) {

        $inQuestion = array($_POST['inQuestion']);
        $inAnswer = array($_POST['inAnswer']);
        $inA = $_POST['inA'] ? $_POST['inA'] : null;
        $inB = $_POST['inB'] ? $_POST['inB'] : null;
        $inC = $_POST['inC'] ? $_POST['inC'] : null;
        $inD = $_POST['inD'] ? $_POST['inD'] : null;
        $inLesson = $_POST['inLesson'];
        $inQuizNo = $_POST['inQuizNo'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE title='$inLesson'";
        $query = mysql_query ($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $lessonID = $row['lessonID'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (question, answer, A, B, C, D, lessonID, quizNo) VALUES ('$question', '$answer', '$inA', '$inB', '$inC', '$inD', '$lessonID', $inQuizNo)";
            $query = mysql_query( $sql ); 
    }
?>

<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>Create Assessment - Multiple Choice</h4>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">

    <form method="post">

        <br>

        <div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <strong>Lesson</strong><br>
                <select class="form-control" name="inLesson">
                    <option></option>
                    <option disabled></option>

                    <?php
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE courseID='$_GET[courseID]'";
                        $query2 = mysql_query ($sql2);                          
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
                    ?>

                        <option><?php echo $row2['title']; ?></option>

                    <?php   } ?>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <strong>Quiz No.</strong><br>                   
                <input required type="number" class="form-control" name="inQuizNo" min="1" max="100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="pull-right">
                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" class="btn btn-info">
                <input type="button" value="Remove" id="removeButton" class="btn btn-warning">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br><br><br><br><br>

        <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
            <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="form-group">

                <h2><span class="label label-primary">No. 1</span></h2>
                <br><br>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>Question</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inQuestion[]' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Answer</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inAnswer[]' class="form-control">
                    <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>A</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inA' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>B</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inB' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>C</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inC' class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>D</label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='inD' class="form-control">
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" name="btnCreate"  class="btn btn-success pull-right">Create Quiz
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doen't work sir. It gives me a notice that "Array to string conversion on the sql statement".

Comment: try my answer again , I did some edit to your html and you php code

Answer (score 0):

rather than posting a detailed solution, play with how to insert multiple rows to get some ideas

Something like:

```
$_POST['inQuestion'] = array(
  'q1','q2','q3' // from input array name 'inQuestion[]'
);

$_POST['inAnswer'] = array(
  'a1','a2','a3' // from input array name 'inAnswer[]'
);

$_POST['other'] = 'sunshine';

$_POST['yet_another'] = 'nice weather';

foreach($_POST['inQuestion'] as $k => $v){
$inserts[] = "(".$v.",".$_POST['inAnswer'][$k].",".$_POST['other'].",".$_POST['yet_another'].")";
}

echo "INSERT INTO table col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 VALUES ".implode(',',$inserts)."";

// INSERT INTO table col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 VALUES (q1,a1,sunshine,nice weather),(q2,a2,sunshine,nice weather),(q3,a3,sunshine,nice weather)
```